# Having trouble on making a yes or no question

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a yes or no question in which yes would equal the value(DEFAULT_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER) and no would direct you to input any value want between 0 and 3; the yes portion works, but the no portion doesn't. What am I missing on this?

```
def get_multiplier():
    chosen_multiplier = -1

    while chosen_multiplier == input("Default multiplier is 1.5, Do you want that? (yes or no):"):
        if chosen_multiplier == "yes" or "Yes":
            chosen_multiplier = DEFAULT_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER
        elif chosen_multiplier = "no" or "No":
            chosen_multiplier < MINIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER or chosen_multiplier > MAXIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER
            chosen_multiplier = float(input("Between 0 and 3, what is your overtime multiplier value? (Default is 1.5):" ))
        else:
            chosen_multiplier < MINIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER or chosen_multiplier > MAXIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER
            print("Invalid value, the overtime multiplier is between 0 and 3.")
    return chosen_multiplier
```

Comment: See, for instance, [How to test multiple variables against a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value)

Answer (score 0):

You have single equality sign in line 7. Also you can't assign value in condition. What's more lines 8 and 11 don't do anything `chosen_multiplier < MINIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER or chosen_multiplier > MAXIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER`.

```
while True:
    choose = input("Default multiplier is 1.5, Do you want that? (yes or no):")
    if choose == "yes" or "Yes":
        chosen_multiplier = DEFAULT_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER
    elif chosen_multiplier = "no" or "No":
        chosen_multiplier = float(input("Between 0 and 3, what is your overtime multiplier value? (Default is 1.5):" ))
    if chosen_multiplier < MINIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER or chosen_multiplier > MAXIMUM_OVERTIME_MULTIPLIER:
        print("Invalid value, the overtime multiplier is between 0 and 3.")
    else:
        break
```

That may not do exactly what you want, but that's as much as I can understand and should give you some ideas.

Comment: i did that but still no good

Comment: if you "***did that***", update your question. and "***still no good***",  doesn't help anyone, **be specific**.

Comment: how about this, does it make sense that i have two inputs in that function?

Comment: If you want additional information from user then it's very sensible.